# Angular4 Routing: ResolveStart event never ends

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have an Angular 4 app using hash routing from a custom `<base href="/long/required/path/index.html">`. This is done because requirements state that this url must be the root of the project. I am attempting to use hash routing to solve this.

The problem I'm seeing involves resolving data for a given route. Given a url `localhost:8000/long/require/path/index.html#/project/1/document/55`

and the `app.routes.ts`

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
 {
  path: 'project/:projectId/document/:documentId',
  component: DocumentViewerComponent,
  resolve: { document: DataResolver}
 },
 { path: '**',    component: NoContentComponent }
];
```

The resolver here runs and retrieves the data as intended.

```
@Injectable()
export class DataResolver implements Resolve<Document> {

constructor(
 private docService: DocumentService,
) { }

public resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<Document> {
this.docService.getDocument(route.params.workspaceId,route.params.documentId)
  .subscribe(d => {
    console.log('Document received, waiting for components to load?', d);
    this.docService.documentRecieved(d);
  }
);
 return this.docService.recievedDocument$;
 }
}
```

documentService

```
@Injectable()
export class DocumentService {
  private recievedDocumentSource = new Subject<Document>();

  recievedDocument$ = this.recievedDocumentSource.asObservable();

  documentRecieved(document: Document) {
    this.recievedDocumentSource.next(document);
  }

}
```

The intent here is that the other components can subscribe to `recievedDocument$` and get the new documents information. This currently works and other components get the document by subscribing to this `Observable`. However, the `<router-outlet>` never renders my main component and after checking some `ActivatedRoute` snapshots, the router enters the `ResolveStart` router event but never gets to the `ResolveEnd` event.

1) Is the approach sound? Does this make sense?

2) Any idea why I would be hanging in this ResolveStart state?

Disclaimer: code has been simplified, so I'm looking for the conceptual flaw more than syntactic

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The ResolveEnd isn't triggred because the Observable isn't completed. So, try to finish the Observable just after the next call. The missing event should be emitted.

Internally, Angular use concatMap operator which wait for completion before  notifying the observers.